# How to automate updating a trac wiki page?

Tags: python, automation, wiki, trac

I have a trac wiki page I'd like to update automatically on a regular basis (say, once an hour) with data fetched by a script.

I can get the script to generate the wiki markup.

How would you then upload that to the trac page? I want to replace the whole body of the page.

I would prefer a solution in python, as the rest of the stack (trac, fetching scripts) also use that. Just a pointer in the right direction should be enough ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install the Trac XMLRPC plugin:

http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/XmlRpcPlugin

and then use the xmlrpc client library from the standard library. Then you'll be able to manipulate most aspects of Trac (tickets, wiki pages, etc) from a Python script.

Answer (score 0):

I had a hard time getting the XmlRpcPlugin to work, details in the trac ticket: http://trac-hacks.org/ticket/6035#comment:7

Answer (score -1):

u can try and use
http://perlmediawikiapi.wikia.com/wiki/Perl_MediaWiki_API_Wiki

Comment: How is this in any way related to the question (except for the fact that it contains the word “Wiki”? It’s about perl, not python and about MediaWiki, not Trac Wiki…